# What's the easiest way to create passport-sized prints?

Tags: prints, service-recommendation, software-recommendation

I need to print some passport-sized photos for visa applications. They each need to be 35mm x 45mm.

Is there an easy way to take a single photo of my face and create a new jpeg file from it that I can just print in 6"x4" and have several passport photos on it in the right size that I can just cut out?

Comment: I realize the question is 5 years old, but the details were not answered. For others interested in passport photos, here are the USA passport photo requirements (a good thing to know if you are going to try it): http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/photos/photos.html You can find the same thing online for Canada, UK, etc.

Comment: Link in case anyone is looking for UK spec - note they accept printed or digital these days (including ones taken directly from your computer camera!) - https://www.gov.uk/photos-for-passports

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since asking this question, and answering my own question I've faced the same problem so many times that I decided to write a website that solves it in a nice free way. You just  upload a photo and then you can just download a jpeg ready to print at 6"x4".

[www.oddprints.com](http://www.oddprints.com)

[image: oddprints]

Output photo:
[image]

Sorry if this is a bit spammy, but it is a free website, no need to register, doesn't watermark the image or anything like that and the source is free [on github](https://github.com/mattburns/OddPrints) etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use any photo or printing program to print several on the same page. Windows printing will do this as well. If you're on a Mac, you should be able to use Preview to print several JPEGs opened in the same window. Just make sure that scaling and anything other size related settings are set so that your images print at the size they should be.

As for the size, 35x45mm is 413x531 pixels at 300DPI. You may want to print them with a few mm of bleed.

If you really wanted to though, you could use Photoshop to just generate your own collage of passport photos on an A4 sized template.

Have the passports resized to 413x531px, create a new A4 image in Photoshop (or any image editing program you want to use) then drag or paste in the images and assemble them.

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of Picasa actually have a passport photo feature, it is in the "Tools" menu.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a promising start, but it silently assumes you want US-size passport photos (2"x2").
So no good for me.

Answer (score 2):

As answered by @nick the photo dimensions of 35x45mm translate to 413x513px at 300DPI. On top of that, you may have to look for biometric requirements (eg. size of the head, distance of the head from the top) from official sources. The common do-it-yourself technique is editing your photo accordingly in photoshop.

(Shameless plug) Having gone through that journey I created [www.MakePassportPhoto.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uilmy.png) to scratch my own itch. It's free for doing it yourself. The overlay silhouette is the standout feature, it helps to set the right biometrics for 500+ document types.

35x45mm photo for 6x4 paper :

[image]